# While loops vs loop-do

Tags: ruby, loops, while-loop

I'm working on code to find the lowest common multiple of two integers. I first wrote the code as a while loop and it would not return any value to the command line. Here is the while loop:

```
def find_common_multiple(x, y)
  z = 0
  while z % x != 0 && z % y != 0 do
    puts z
    z += 1
  end
end

find_common_multiple(4, 6)
=>nil
```

As I understand it the while loop will keep running until the while condition is no longer evaluated as true. First off I understand that as my code is currently written it would stop one number shy of the the actual lowest common multiple.  I'm not worried about that aspect, I just don't understand why it isn't running at all.

I was curious to see if I could get it to work using another type of loop. Using loop-do I was able to solve the problem.  Here is that code:

```
def find_common_multiple(x, y)
  z = 0
  loop do
    z += 1
    if z % x === 0 && z % y === 0 
        puts z
    else
        nil
    end
    break if z % x === 0 && z % y === 0
  end

end

find_common_multiple(4, 6)
12
=>nil
```

I don't understand why the while loop doesn't run but the loop-do does. Is my syntax wrong on the while loop or am I not understanding a fundamental principle of how it operates?  Any clarification on this subject would be much appreciated.  Thank you!

p.s. this is my first question and I've referenced the guidelines but if you notice any that I haven't followed I would appreciate that feedback as well.

Comment: There’s no reason to use `===` here, `==` will do just fine (and makes more sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop does not run because `0 % 4 == 0` (as well as `0 % 6 == 0`) so the very first condition returns `false` and the loop is never executed.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - exactly, and the condition is `z % x != 0` which is always `false` for if `z == 0`

Comment: Correct. And on top of that, there is no point in starting the loop with `0` when the OP wants to get the LCM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that now makes complete sense.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a OR not an AND operation:

```
def find_common_multiple(x, y)
  z = x > y  ?  x : y
  puts "#{z} ist the bigger of the two and the lowest possible candidate to be the lowest common multiple"
  while z % x != 0 || z % y != 0 do
    z += 1
  end
  puts z
end
```

**THE REASON WHY IT DIDNT WORK FOR YOU:**

You'ew starting with a zero. 0 % 4 != 0 is false and 0 % 6 != 0 is also false so it won't even enter the while loop.

**WHY ||, NOT &&**

Because you want it to go for as long as both of the numbers give something else then zero as the remainder. With the && evaluator, it would stop as soon ONE of the expressions are true.

**FROM WHERE TO START**

Also i started off with the bigger of the two candidates since it is the lowest possible candidate to be the lowest common multiple.

Comment: That's also a good point. Thanks! I wish I could check your answer as well or at least up vote it but unfortunately I don't have a high enough reputation to up vote yet.